# Trying to develop an App on BREW MP

Tags: signature, brew-framework, brewmp

The handset maker bypassed the Qualcomm/BREW certification or authentication process. The phone only runs on the Sprint Network. I cannot access developer mode because I lack the required signature. I registered with BREW dev team, etc. Since the phone was never certified through BREW, I'm being told that I cannot obtain the signature from BREW. Can I obtain this signature from Sprint or the Hand-Set maker? Do they have to give it to me or charge me for it? Any other ideas would be appreciated.

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

I think they could but they won't. Or even Sprint might not have the ability, they might only have signing keys given to them from BREW/Qualcomm for their use only. Either way, I recommend you get another phone, and pick one which has as many "grandfathered" devices as possible, this will reduce testing if you ever decide to release your app on one of the stores.